# KDB function call from java

Tags: java, kdb

I have a kdb function which takes dictionary as param. Filter condition need to be provided as wClause key.

fun:{[dic] }

e.g.
wClause:enlist(in;`sym;enlist` sym1`sym2)

because if I use string it will be send as `in or if I use characterArray it will be "in".

how to build above wClasue in Java? what's the way to call kdb functions from java e.g. "in,like".

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide context of how you are currently querying kdb with Java? Also do you have control over the kdb function that handles this?

Comment: I am using c.java. I do not have control over kdb function. https://code.kx.com/q/wp/java-api/#running-queries-using-k-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test table + query. With a small functional select helper funtion:

```
q)test:([] a:1 2 3;b:`a`b`c)
q)test
a b
---
1 a
2 b
3 c
q)select from test where a in 1 2,b like "a*"
a b
---
1 a
q)?[test;((in;`a;1 2);(like;`b;"a*"));0b;()]
a b
---
1 a
q)fsel:{[t;wc] ?[t;wc;0b;()]}
q)fsel[`test;((in;`a;1 2);(like;`b;"a*"))]
a b
---
1 a
```

You cannot send the `in` or `like` operators directly from the java interface as the serializer does not produce this datatype.

You can however send [parse trees](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/parsetrees/) which will evaluate them:

```
q)value"in"
in
q)eval(`$".q.value";"in")
in
q)?[test;(((`.q.value;"in");`a;1 2);((`.q.value;"like");`b;"a*"));0b;()]
a b
---
1 a
```

From Java:

```java
c c=new c("localhost",5000);
Object[]wc=new Object[]{
    new Object[]{new Object[]{".q.value","in".toCharArray()},"a",new long[] {1,2}},
    new Object[]{new Object[]{".q.value","like".toCharArray()},"b","a*".toCharArray()}
 };
Object result=c.k("fsel","test",wc);
```

[image: Java object]